# Validity of local auto-correlation in the presence of global auto-correlation

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, local-statistics

I'm just wondering if someone could clarify something for me regarding spatial auto-correlation. 
I've been reading up on Moran's I (global and local) and Gi* statistics, and saw that at the end of Anselin (1995) he writes

> Firstly, the LISA generalize the idea underlying the Getis and Ord Gi
>   and Gi* statistics to a broad class of measures of local spatial
>   association. Secondly, by directly linking the local indicators to a
>   global measure of spatial association, the decomposition of the latter
>   into its observation-specific components becomes straightforward,
>   thus enabling the assessment of influential observations and outliers.
>   It is this dual property that distinguishes the class of LISA from
>   existing techniques, such as the Gi and Gi* statistics and the Moran
>   scatterplot. The LISA presented here are easy to implement and lend
>   themselves readily to visualization. They thus serve a useful purpose
>   in an exploratory analysis of spatial data, potentially indicating
>   local spatial clusters and forming the basis for a sensitivity
>   analysis (outliers). While the former is more appropriate when no
>   global spatial autocorrelation is present, the latter is particularly
>    useful when there is spatial autocorrelation in the data...Furthermore, the uncritical use of the null distribution in
>   the presence of global spatial autocorrelation will give incorrect
>   significance levels. The problem also pertains to the Gi and Gi*
>   statistics and would suggest that a test for global spatial
>   autocorrelation should precede the assessment of significant local
>   spatial clusters.

I've interpreted this as essentially saying it is not appropriate to look for local indicators of spatial auto-correlation (using for e.g. Local Moran's I) in the presence of global spatial-autocorrelation, but that's it's appropriate to examine the same datasets for hot (or cold) spots using Gi*? How should you interpret significant Local Moran's I and significant Gi* statistics (regardless of whether or not P-values have been corrected) in the presence of global auto-correlation?